# How to get partial code of a function with assigned values?

Tags: function, variables, python-3.x, assign

Consider this simple function:

```
>>> def foo(a):
...     x = 2
...     term = x + a
...     return term
... 
>>> foo(2)
4
>>>
```

Now along with the result I would like to have the code of the `term` with its assigned values like this:

```
@ example
>>> foo(2)
4, 'term = 2 + 2'
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: To what purpose? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Python executes *bytecode*; a set of numeric instructions that the compiler produced from the source code. The interpreter doesn't execute `term = x + a`. It executes 2 `LOAD_FAST` operations, a `BINARY_ADD` and a `STORE_FAST`. Those instructions can be traced back to their source code again, but you generally try to avoid tracing as that's a huge speed impediment. You'd only do that when debugging or profiling (producing relative speed measurements).

Comment: I'm building a little website with Flask which does a little since computing. I'm able to highlight my Python code for documentation. But now I would like to show the used function with its assigned values (like Mathcad). And therefor I need Python providing that peace of code which later can be rendered somehow.

Comment: Python doesn't have any functionality out of the box to do this. You'd have to do your own introspection (perhaps analyse the tree produced by the `ast` module) then extract the corresponding source code.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the [TeXcalc](https://github.com/rsmith-nl/texcalc) module to do something similar. It takes calculations and both formats them nicely for LaTeX and calculates the results.

It uses the `ast` module but also `eval` and `exec`, so it shouldn't be used with untrusted input.

The formatting is done by a custom object derived from the `ast.NodeVisitor` class. This was the hardest part to get right. It should at least give you an idea how to do this.